# String missing while using :eq() Selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string

i use jQuery to read String from  and pass it into PHP, then Insert/Edit the DataBase. 
My Problem is that whithin this process, i missing Large Strings and they Never save to DataBase, and i can not Edit them! i i have a large string, i can not edit that. the code got crash!

**Have :eq() Selector Limitation for String Size?!**

my code to select String is:

```
 $(document).on("click",".edit_button",function() {
     $(this).parents("tr").each(function(index) {
     $("*").css("cursor", "wait");
         id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
         comment = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data:{ comment : comment , job : "edit"},
            dataType:"html",success:function(result){   
                $("*").css("cursor","auto"); 
                $(".edit_button").css("cursor", "pointer");  
                    document.getElementById("items_body").innerHTML=result;             
                }
        });

    }); 
});
```

and the PHP code on file ajax.php is:

```
$job=$_GET["job"];
if ($job=="edit")
{
    $comment=$_GET["comment"];
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $sql_command="UPDATE items SET comment='$comment' WHERE id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql_command,$con);
}
```

Comment: Try sending the request using post method. Get method has some limitation while sending the data.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing `id` in your ajax call

```
data:{ comment : comment , job : "edit", id : id },
```

> There is no limitation for `eq()`, limitation is for get method. So it's better to use post instead.